# calculate std::distance between two std::reverse_iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, reverse-iterator

I have a code snippet like this:

```
int* array = new int[size];
std::reverse_iterator<int*> it2 = ... // arbitrary in array
```

How can i compute the distance between last and `it2`?
I tried this, but it gives back zero:

```
std::distance(std::reverse_iterator<int*>(array + size), it2);
```

Comment: 1. You don't show how `it2` is created so how can we know why it's broken 2. if you want to use the stdlib just use `std::array` much more user friendly than old cstyle arrays 3. also std distance works exactly the same for reverse iterators as normal iterators

Comment: Your suspicion was right, the fetching of `it2` was incorrect.
I cannot use `std::array`, because it only supports constant size arrays.

Comment: Then ideally you would want to use `std::dynarray` (maybe available c++14, boost prolly already has something like it) but IMO for now `std::vector` is a better replacement than a cstyle array, who wants to manage their own memory :P

Comment: @aaronman - `dynarray` won't be in C++14. Too many unforeseen complications.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's why I said maybe, I heard they are removing optional too, that really pissed me off, I had some code using boost::optional with the intention that I would replace it with std::optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to computing the distance looks correct to me. Certainly, this prints `10` when using [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const int size = 20;
    int* array = new int[size];
    std::cout << "distance="
              << std::distance(std::reverse_iterator<int*>(array + 20),
                               std::reverse_iterator<int*>(array + 10))
              << '\n';
    delete[] array;
}
```